# GlobCover 2009 dataset - importing legend and colormap values into R

Tags: raster, r, legend, land-cover, colormap

Does anyone know how to import a legend for a raster layer (loaded as a .tif) into R such that it can be attached to the raster file itself and used in plotting?

In this case, I am using the GLC2009 V2.3 data, available from: http://due.esrin.esa.int/page_globcover.php

The legend is stored separately as a .xls file, as well as .lyr and .dsr files. I believe the latter 2 extensions are for ArcINFO files but regardless I have never used either in R.

I can import the .xls legend as follows easily:

```
    GLC_Legend <- read.xlsx("./Globcover2009_V2.3/Globcover2009_Legend.xls", 
            sheetIndex=1, header=TRUE)
    head(GLC_Legend)

    #   Value                                                     Label Red Green Blue
    # 1    11         Post-flooding or irrigated croplands (or aquatic) 170   240  240
    # 2    14                                         Rainfed croplands 255   255  100
```

But I am lost as to how I could utilize this data frame to re-create the color map, as well as to how I could use the .lyr or .dsr files in its stead. Any know-how on importing colormaps from files for mapping purposes in R would be wonderful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a paletted raster by assigning a colortable in the legend.

If you have a raster called `r` and a data frame like yours above called `ctab`, with value and red/green/blue colour values, you can do something like this:

```
> ctable = rep(NA,max(ctab$value)+1)
> ctable[ctab$value+1] = 
      rgb(ctab$red,ctab$green,ctab$blue,maxColorValue=255)
> r@legend@colortable = ctable
> plot(r)
```

Note the +1s are needed because the colortable starts at zero (I think).

Comment: You're the bomb! Had to rearrange your code just slightly but the rgb() function was just what I needed. Worked like a charm. Didn't have a ton of familiarity with grDevices package but I'll read up on it now, for sure. Thanks for the input!

Comment: The colortable stuff in package:raster is poorly documented, there's not even any real functions for it which is why you end up setting the colours explicitly with @-stuff. Maybe I'll write some helper functions and see if Rob H wants to put them in the package...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. Then I checked the download page again:

```
A coloured version of the map in GeoTIFF format:
http://due.esrin.esa.int/files/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2.3.color.tif
```

For those of us who don't want to go through the trouble of recreating the colored map with R.

Answer (score 0):

As an extra, you can easily convert the "Globcover2009_Legend.xls" into a CSV file, then import the CSV easily into R:

```
# XLS --> CSV
ogr2ogr -f CSV Globcover2009_Legend.csv Globcover2009_Legend.xls
R
> globcover_legend <- read.csv("Globcover2009_Legend.csv")
> str(globcover_legend)
'data.frame':   23 obs. of  5 variables:
$ Value: int  11 14 20 30 40 50 60 70 90 100 ...
$ Label: Factor w/ 23 levels "Artificial surfaces and associated areas (Urban areas >50%)",..: 20 21 12 15 6 3 17 5 18 11 ...
$ Red  : int  170 255 220 205 0 0 170 0 40 120 ...
$ Green: int  240 255 240 205 100 160 200 60 100 130 ...
$ Blue : int  240 100 100 102 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```